# retrieve matching song URI from Spotify API

Tags: javascript, api, uri, spotify

I have been using Javascript to try and retrieve the URI of a song from the Spotify WEB API using the below code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=foo", false);
xhr.send();
var uri = (xhr.track);
</script>
```

I want to put in a song name as the 'q' parameter and store the uri of the top result in a variable. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the response as JSON and then pick the href attribute of the first object in the tracks list.

In code, following your example, it could look like this:

`var uri = JSON.parse(xhr.response).tracks[0].href;`